# Is there a way to list packages for upgrade in apt upgrade as "list view" with line breaks instead of all clumped together?

Tags: apt

I take interest in seeing which packages are being upgraded when I run apt-get upgrade and it would be much easier on the eyes if it there were a way to simply list everything line by line instead of all clumped together.

Right after the message "The following packages will be upgraded:" it usually looks something like this:

apport apport-gtk bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs distro-info-data djvulibre-bin dnsutils firefox firefox-locale-en google-chrome

Does anyone know of some switch I can add to get them to appear like this instead?

apport
apport-gtk
bind9-dnsutils
bind9-host
bind9-libs
distro-info-data
djvulibre-bin
dnsutils
firefox
firefox-locale-en
google-chrome

This is obviously not a major issue or anything urgent, it's just something over the years which has had me wondering if there was a better way to separate and quickly scan the list of packages.

I'm just curious if this is possible to make this section much easier to read.  Every other line of what's processing I can quickly scan vertically only to get hung up trying to take the time to mentally separate each package by spaces.

Answer (score 4):

There’s no way to show exactly what you want, short of post-processing `apt`’s output, but if you ask `apt` to show version details for the upgraded packages, it will show one package per line:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade -V
...
The following packages will be upgraded:
   ansilove (4.0.4-1 => 4.1.4-1)
   binutils-djgpp (2.34-3+1.4 => 2.35.1+dfsg-1)
   binutils-mingw-w64 (2.31.1-16+8.3.1 => 2.35-2+8.11)
   bochsbios (2.6.11+dfsg-3 => 2.6.11+dfsg-4)
   drmips (2.0.1-2 => 2.0.1-2.1)
   frotz (2.52-0.1 => 2.53+dfsg-1)
...
```

You can enable this permanently by setting the `APT::Get::Show-Versions` option to `true`, for example in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
APT::Get::Show-Versions "true";
```